GraphicsGrid and PlotRangeClipping
the following command creates a strange output:
Show[GraphicsGrid[{{Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}]}, {Plot[
     x^3, {x, 0, 1}]}, {Plot[x^4, {x, 0, 1}]}}], 
 PlotRangeClipping -> True]

The grid gets cropped, which is probably no user ever would want?!

What I would like to do is to be able to with a function myShow[], which accepts plots and GraphicsGrids, and which applies PlotRangeClipping. Buf since both the result of Plot[] and GraphicsGrid[] is a Graphics object, I cannot easily distinguish the two.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

It is not clear to me what is your problem. It seems that you are not satisfied with the result of GraphicsGrid[{{Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}]}, {Plot[x^3, {x, 0, 1}]}, {Plot[x^4, {x, 0, 1}]}}]. Would you explain what kind of effects do you want by using PlotRangeClipping?

My point is: I would like to write a function 'myShow[]', that can take options like PlotRangeClipping, and that would work on the output of a GraphicsGrid as well as on that of simpler constructs like the output of a plain Plot[]. This seems not to work, as in the former case the PlotRangeClipping destroys the plot ...

I'm asking ... what your ideal output would be if "PlotRangeClipping" did not destroy the plot?

That would simply be the same as it would be without the "PlotRangeClipping" option!

Thank you. You already know how to obtain the ideal output... I wish someone could answer your question.
